# How to track Google Plus +1 (plusone) clicks on Google Analytics with analytics.js

Tags: google-analytics, google-plus

I am trying to get information about Google+ +1 clicks into Google Analytics.  This apparently functions out of the box if you use the "classic" tracking mechanism - using ga.js.  However we are using the newer "analytics.js" option.  The developer page about social interaction for analytics here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/social-interactions says the following:

> Currently, the analytics.js library does not automatically measure
>   Google+ social interactions (unlike, ga.js social interaction tracking
>   which does). To measure Google+ interactions, you must explicitly
>   implement social interaction.

So, how do you "explicitly implement social interaction" for Google+?

I have managed to gather analytics information for Facebook and Twitter buttons using callbacks, and expect there will be a similar mechanism for Google+ but I am completely astonished how little information there is online about how to do this.  I have spent about 2 hours Googling with next to no leads.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 4):

For the plusone button you can use a **callback** option to specify javascript that sends the event to google analytics.

Documentation is available here:

https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/

Sample code that implements a Google Analytics callback looks something like this:

```
<script>
  gapi.plusone.render('mydiv',
    {'callback': function(params) {
      if (param['state'] === 'on') {
        ga('send', 'google', 'plusone', param['plusone']);
      },
      'size': 'tall'
    }
</script>
```

If you want to use +1 markup you can define the callback function in the global namespace, then refer to it in the **callback** attribute.

```
 <div class="g-plusone" data-callback="mycallback"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Paul.  I ended up reverting to ga.js so can't confirm if your answer solves the problem.  I will no doubt revisit this in time though and will update when appropriate. +1 for useful information anyway.